# How to loop the $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs);

Tags: php, loops, phpmyadmin

I have a table 
[image]

Now.i have a function in my JS

```
function add()


{      
                <?php 
include('conn.php');
$rs = mysql_query("select * from position");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
$ss=$row['Name']; 
$sss=$row['nowb'];
$ssss=$row['totalb'];
$sssss=$row['nowc'];
$ssssss=$row['totalc'];
echo "add2()";
?>}

function add2(){
         AddAddress("<?php echo $ss;?>","<?php echo $sss;?>/<?php echo $ssss;?><br /><?php echo $sssss;?>/<?php echo $ssssss;?>");
         }
```

How to get the every date from my table?

Comment: Really? Raw PHP code inside JS code? :D

Comment: Yes.Its ok ....But i dont know how to loop them..

Comment: @Jari No thats PHP code generating Javascript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
function add() {      
<?php 
include('conn.php');
$rs = mysql_query("select * from position");
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs) ) {
  $ss=$row['Name']; 
  $sss=$row['nowb'];
  $ssss=$row['totalb'];
  $sssss=$row['nowc'];
  $ssssss=$row['totalc'];
  echo 'AddAddress("' . $ss . '","' . $sss . '/' . $ssss . '<br />' . $sssss . '/' . $ssssss . '");';
}
?>
}
```

Didn't text the echo 'AddAddress....' line so I hop eI got all the single and double quotes in the right place??

Answer (score 0):

[Performing POST requests using Ajax](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/ajaxgetpost2.shtml) here is an example of sending data from js to php.

also stop naming your vars s,ss,sss,ssss you will have no idea what they mean when you read your code tomorrow..

and try not to use mysql_* functions they have been deprecated switch to [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) or [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: :)   i am very anxious...so..ssssssssssss .

Answer (score 0):

I got what would you like to do. In your PHP file:

```
function add(){
<?php
include('conn.php');
$rs = mysql_query("select * from position");
echo "var data = [] ; "
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){
  echo "
    data.push({
      name:   '{$row['Name']}',
      nowb:   '{$row['nowb']}',
      totalb: '{$row['totalb']}',
      nowc:   '{$row['nowc']}',
      totalc: '{$row['totalc']}'
    }); \n\r " ;
}
?>
add2(data);
}

function add2(data){
  for (var i in data){
    var row = data[i] ;
    AddAddress(row.name, row.nowb, row.totalb, row.nowc, row.totalc);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly you want to know how to loop through an array in php.

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
foreach($row as $value){
    //Do something
}
```

Read up on it in the docs
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php